# Spring JPA join tables without relationship and math operation

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables `Project_Products(id, product_id, version, name)` and `Cos_Product(cos_id, version,  description)`

Now I need to join the tables on `Project_Products.product_id = Cos_Product.cos_id` and create a column isConflict whose value is going to be 0 or 1 based on if Project_Products.version = Cos_Product.version

Currently I'm running it by using native query using Hibernate Entity Manager. This works perfectly fine by using the query

```
Select p.id, p.project_id, p.name, 
case when p.version = c.version then 0 else 1 as is_conflict 
from Project_Products p left join Cos_Product c on p.product_id = c.cos_id
```

Now how to do this scenario using spring jpa? Without using native query.

Comment: Can you please post the code of the two classes so we can have better idea.

Comment: Do you need `Project_Products` entity as result or `List<Object[]>` is fine?

Comment: Yes having it as List of Object[] is fine

Comment: JPA uses classes/fields not tables/columns. You can't ask people to tell you what query if you dont post the basic info

Comment: If you have a perfectly working solution, why do you want to change the underlying technology? What is the real problem you want to solve?

Comment: datasources. Postgres and Oracle. Same tables. To make it work in both want to use spring jpa.